# When will the Unity Greeter begin to look like the propositions from the Design Team?

Tags: lightdm, design, unity-greeter

The Canonical Design Team gave a rather beautiful login screen mockup for the unity greeter. These designs, in my opinion far exceed the current UI that we have for Quantal (which I think is worse, apart from remote login), and I was led to beleive that these were the official guidelines for the greeter.

Are there plans to implement these designs into the Unity Greeter?

The proposal is here: https://docs.google.com/a/canonical.com/document/d/1ypvxcSmwNKKMZawit-0r6uLnbTxoA-XoyB0ZNCKNMSg/edit?pli=1

The mockups are here: https://docs.google.com/a/canonical.com/file/d/0BzP7juF4TDpQS3JCWmtHTmR6OVk/edit?pli=1

Comment: This.Is.Beautiful!

Comment: Not all propositions and mock ups make it to the final working design. We would live in a rather beautiful world if they did.

Comment: But there is no reason why it shouldn't! We should have had transparent panels ages ago. The Design team seem to be quite ignored...

Comment: that and when the "login box resizes and scales vertically" it scales off the screen...

Comment: Most of it has been implemented, and I think they didn't have enough time to implement everything, so it will be in the release.

Comment: The answer is: how do I know? I'm just a member of the community! Voted to close as not constructive.

Comment: Although this was not an unreasonable question, and often members of the community *do* know when something is going to happen in the development of Ubuntu because it's been publicly announced, or there is other public information that would lead to objectively good (or at least ["good subjective"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)) guesses ...here, there is no indication that this question can be answered by anyone (community member, Canonical employee, or anyone else) now or in the immediate future. So I am also voting to close this as *not constructive*.